# Can't seem to read file into a matrix?

Tags: java, matrix

```
public void getMatrix() throws FileNotFoundException{

File file = new File("C:/Users/Cameron/Desktop/words.txt");
String largest =" ";
int col = 0;
int count=0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    Scanner newsc = new Scanner(file);

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String i = sc.nextLine();
        count++;

         if(i.length()>largest.length()){
            largest=i;
            col = largest.length();

        }

    }

  int rows = (int)(Math.random()*count +1);  

  String data[][] = new String[rows][col];

  while(newsc.hasNextLine()){
    String c = newsc.nextLine();

    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<col; j++ ){

        data[i][j] = c;

    }
    }
  }

    for(int r=0; r<data.length; r++)
    {
        for(int c=0; c<data[0].length; c++)
        {
            System.out.print(data[r][c]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();  //Moves to next line
    }

}
```

I am trying to read words from a file (for now, I need to make them characters later) but I'm having trouble reading the words into the matrix. The matrix has is supposed to be of a random size but it is supposed to take into account the longest word in the set range of words that are going to be read in. I got the length of the longest word for the columns of the matrix and then I got a random number for the rows based on the number of words in the file. Whenever I print the matrix it prints just one word throughout the whole thing. I know this is because of the while loop and double for loop combination only taking in the first word of the file but I can't seem to figure out a way to fix it.

Here's what I want to see (to an extent):

```
ladybug hamburger lettuce computer compiler java cologne
book encyclopedia dictionary guitar euphonium nutcracker
mouthpiece outlet calculus lightsaber
```

Here's what I actually see (again, to an extent):

```
lightsaber lightsaber lightsaber lightsaber lightsaber lightsaber
lightsaber lightsaber lightsaber lightsaber lightsaber lightsaber
lightsaber lightsaber lightsaber lightsaber lightsaber lightsaber
lightsaber lightsaber lightsaber lightsaber lightsaber lightsaber
```

Comment: Can you clarify this? (In your question, not in a comment). For example, you can post what you expect the input, what you expect to see in the matrix, and what you actually see in the matrix.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
while(newsc.hasNextLine()){
    String c = newsc.nextLine();

    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<col; j++ ){

        data[i][j] = c;

    }
    }
  }
```

you are replacing every value of `data` with `c`

try

```
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){

      for(int j=0; j<col; j++ ){

        if (newsc.hasNextLine()){
           String c = newsc.nextLine();
           data[i][j] = c;
        }

      }
    }
```

Also the finally loop should be

```
for(int r=0; r<data.length; r++)
{
    for(int c=0; c<data[r].length; c++)
    {
        System.out.print(data[r][c]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();  //Moves to next line
}
```

Comment: I understand that the c is a constant in this case but how do I go about reading in the next line after it's been placed into the matrix?

Comment: This throws `NoSuchElementException: No line found`

Comment: Think about when you read a line in your loops. Right now your code goes through all the words in the list and writes each of them into every place in the array once. Hence the matrix will have the end state of being filled with the last word read.

Comment: Updated the for loops

Comment: It throws that exception because you cannot be sure that the largest word's length is lesser than the number of lines in the text file. Why do we want the column of matrix to be the length of the largest word?

Comment: My guess is he is going to transpose the matrix.

Comment: My end goal is to read in character by character but I just figured making either the row or column the size of the longest word would allow for enough space in the matrix